# Как можно сделать свойства обьекта реактивными в Vue

Tags: vue.js

Столкнулся с проблемой что нужно создать динамически объект, но проблема в том что его свойства не реактивны. Делаю через `Vue.set`, но не работает. В чём может быть проблема?

Пытаюсь сделать вот такие объекты:

```
questionCheckbox: {
  hasTooltip: false,
},

answerCheckbox: {
  hasTransform: false,
  hasPopup: false,
  hasTooltip: false,
},
```

а этой функцией я создаю их:

```
const checkboxArrSetConvert = Array.from(checkboxArrSet);
let checkboxObjArr = {};
checkboxArrSetConvert.forEach((item) => {
  checkboxObjArr[item] = false;
});

Vue.set(state, viewType + 'Checkbox', checkboxObjArr)
```

`viewType` - это *question*, *answer*, *...*
а в `checkboxArrSetConvert` лежат названия чекбоксов - *hasTooltip*, *...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема может быть в попытке изменения состояния вне мутации, если используется Vuex.

А если `state` это свойство `date` экземпляра Vue, то все прекрасно работает.
Только в этом случае надо обязательно обращаться к свойствам экземпляра через `this` (если обращение в его методах, а не в шаблоне):

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app', 
  data: {
    state: {}, 
  }, 
  created() {  // для простоты я не создаю отдельный метод
    const checkboxArrSetConvert = ['hasTransform', 'hasPopup', 'hasTooltip'];
    let viewType = 'answer'; 
    let checkboxObj = {};
    checkboxArrSetConvert.forEach((item) => {
      checkboxObj[item] = false;
    });
    Vue.set(this.state, viewType + 'Checkbox', checkboxObj); 

    // демо реактивности, изменение случайного свойства каждые 0,25с 
    setInterval(() => {
      const keys = Object.keys(this.state.answerCheckbox), 
            rndKey = keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)]; 
      this.state.answerCheckbox[rndKey] = !this.state.answerCheckbox[rndKey]; 
    }, 250); 
  }
});
```

```html
<pre id="app">{{ JSON.stringify(state, null, 2) }}</pre>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```